# Change Navigation into walk Navigation with scripting

Tags: python, scripting, navigation

I'm now trying to change Navigation into walk Navigation in the 3D viewport. So I write the code below.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                bpy.ops.view3D.walk()
```

this returns error

```
  File "D:\3Dmodels\python_demos.blend\operator_modal_view3d.py", line 11, in <module>
  File "D:\programs\Blender\stable\blender-2.92.0-windows64\2.92\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.view3D.walk.poll() expected a view3d region
```

So I added a line `override = {'area': area, 'region': region}` and change `walk()` into `walk(override)`.

```
import bpy

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        for region in area.regions:
            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                override = {'area': area, 'region': region}
                bpy.ops.view3D.walk(override)
```

However, Blender returns another error

```
ERROR (wm.operator): C:\b\buildbot-worker-windows\windows_292\blender.git\source\blender\windowmanager\intern\wm_event_system.c:1321 wm_operator_invoke: invalid operator call 'VIEW3D_OT_walk'
```

So if anyone knows how to run `bpy.ops.view3D.walk()`, please teach me and I would be very happy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Putting 3D viewport in walk mode from py console.**

Think you were 99% there.

IMO always a good idea to try things out in the python console

```
>>> C.area.type
'CONSOLE'
```

Override the context by finding a view3d area in the screen. Make sure an area aside from console is a view3d.

```
>>> for a in C.screen.areas:
...     if a.type == 'VIEW_3D':
...         break
...         
>>> a.type
'VIEW_3D'
```

Make a dictionary and fill with usual suspects `area`, `space_data`, and `region`. AFAIK It is always the case that the `'WINDOW'` region is the last in the area regions. If not of this opinion can iterate them as shown in question.

```
>>> c = {}
>>> c["area"] = a
>>> c["space_data"] = a.spaces.active
>>> c["region"] = a.regions[-1]
```

Ok [now give the override a go...](https://docs.blender.org/api/latest/bpy.ops.html#overriding-context) oh and remember all letters in an operator are expected to be  lower case eg `3d` not `3D`.... (*However it does appear to accept `view3D`, but autocompletes on `view3d`*).

```
>>> with C.temp_override(**c):
...    bpy.ops.view3d.walk('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
...     
{'RUNNING_MODAL'}
```

BINGO.. 3D view is in walk mode.

Ok all that done and shown, if you are going to write an operator that is invoked from within the 3d viewport, all the override stuff is not required. (Similarly if you change the area to a 3d viewport as shown by @Chris, but in reality we rarely want to do that way... hard to type into console if it becomes the 3d viewport (for example))  The default execution context of a button or menu pressed is `'INVOKE_DEFAULT'`.

*See the [revisions to this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/214412/revisions) for a version of this answer prior to Blender 3.2.*

Comment: Thank you for your amazing answer! This worked perfectly and helped me to understand it deeply!

Comment: I found out that we only need to override `area` and `region`, https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/230836/31447