# Python access to walk_speed setting of Walk/Fly Navigation Mode

Tags: python, 3d-view

Is it possibile to access walk_speed setting of Walk Navigation mode via python API? (I know how to activate the Walk mode by script, but I want to change the walk speed).

Comment: Voted to reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can access all settings of [`WalkNavigation`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WalkNavigation.html#bpy.types.WalkNavigation.walk_speed) via [Preferences](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Preferences.html#bpy.types.Preferences). Recommend use the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html) to figure out:

```
>>> C.preferences
<bpy_struct, Preferences at 0x1108d8a28>

>>> C.preferences.inputs.walk_navigation.
                                         walk_speed
                                         use_gravity
                                         walk_speed_factor
                                         ...
```

Demo on how to call [`bpy.ops.view3d.walk()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=fly#bpy.ops.view3d.walk) from a script and set the [`walk_speed`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WalkNavigation.html#bpy.types.WalkNavigation.walk_speed) to `23` (default is `2.5`) by [overriding the context](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add) of the operator (the actual [area](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#area-bpy-struct) and the [region](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area.regions)):

**Blender 3.2+**

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

walk_nav = context.preferences.inputs.walk_navigation
walk_nav.walk_speed = 23

for area in context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        with context.temp_override(area=area, region=area.regions[-1]):
            bpy.ops.view3d.walk('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        break
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

C = bpy.context

walk_nav = C.preferences.inputs.walk_navigation
walk_nav.walk_speed = 23

for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = C.copy()
        override['area'] = area
        override["region"] = area.regions[-1]
        bpy.ops.view3d.walk(override, 'INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        break
```

Also see: [Change Navigation into walk Navigation with scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/214394/change-navigation-into-walk-navigation-with-scripting)

Comment: Hello! My question was how to access to the walk_speed setting, not how to activate the Walk/Fly Navigation Mode...

Comment: See my edits @igmar

Comment: Really great. This approach helps in a lot of different situations!